# How do I post a mp3 file to a user's wall in Graph API with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use Facebook Graph API to post a mp3 or mpg file on a user's wall. I tried to run my code for a mp3 file but when I run this code I can only post the message.

```
$attachment = array('message' => 'some message',
        'media' => array('type' => 'music','src' => 'http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3',
        'title' => '15 Step',
                            'artist' => 'Radiohead', 
                            'album' => 'In Rainbows')
);
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

Should I take care of something?

Answer (score 0):

`'type'` should be mp3 not music.